# which von Neumann algebras have many sufficiently normal irreducible representations?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be  a von Neumann algebra. We say that $M$ has  many sufficiently normal irreducible representations, namely $\{\pi_i\}$, if $||a||=\sup ||\pi_i(s)||$. For example the second dual of a C*-algebra does.

I am looking for an equivalent condition for this property in term of type theory or some thing else.

Question: $M=?$  if and only if $M$ has many sufficiently normal irreducible representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An irreducible representation $\pi:M\to B(K)$ has range dense in $B(K)$; but, if $\pi$ is normal, the range is all of $B(K)$. As $\ker\pi$ is a weakly closed ideal of $M$, it is of the form $pM$ for some central projection $p\in M$, and we get $(1-p)M\simeq B(K)$.

In other words, $M$ has sufficiently many normal irreducible representations if and only if $M$ is a direct sum $\bigoplus B(K_j)$.

Comment: Dear Martin, I feel some thing is wrong. Your proof says that every von Neumann algebra is of type I that is impossible. It seems you proved that $M$ is embedded in the direct sum $\bigoplus B(K_j)$ which is always true.

Comment: If every vN algebra has the property you want, your question is pointless, isn't it?  In any case, you would have to point me in the direction of the result that shows that those normal irreps exist for an arbitrarily vN algebra.

Comment: Clearly all von Neumann algebras have not this property. For example the second dual of any C*-algebra has this property and $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ has not. I am looking for any charactrization.

Comment: Of course.  Then, why would my argument "say that every von Neuman algebra is of type I"?

Comment: Since in the end of your argument, it was concluded $M=\bigoplus B(K_j)$ . Every projection in this direct sum dominates even a minimal projection which proves $M$ is of type I.

Comment: A von Neumann algebra $\bigoplus B (K_j) $ is obviously of type I. The question is why you seem to assume that I'm saying that $M $ is an arbitrary von Neumann algebra; what I'm assuming is that $M $ satisfies your property.

Comment: In your argument $M$ is mapped via $x\to \oplus\pi(x)$ into \bigoplus B(K_i)   where $\pi$'s run on   irreducible representations. Why is this embbeding onto?

Comment: First: the $\pi's$ run on **some**, **normal**, irreps. As for the argument, it is a typical Zorn Lemma argument. With the idea from the first paragraph one can construct families of pairwise orthogonal central projections $p_j$ with corresponding normal irreps $\pi_j$. Then use Zorn to get a maximal such family.